# Span block width automatically over multiple smaller blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf

Given the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3.5em, minimum width=4.5em]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [block,align=center](a) {A};
\node [block,align=center,right=1cm of a](b) {B};
\node [block,align=center,below=1cm of a](c) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like that the C-Block, which is below the A- and B-Block takes automatically the width that the A and B Block span. I would like it to look something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this without manually setting the width of the C-Block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `calc` TikZ library.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3.5em, minimum width=4.5em]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [block,align=center](a) {A};
\node [block,align=center,right=1cm of a](b) {B};
\path
  let \p0 = (a.south west),
      \p1 = (b.south east),
      \p2 = ($ (\p0)!.5!(\p1) $)
  in
    node [block, below=1cm of \p2, minimum width=\x1-\x0] (c) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `let` path command lets you define points via `\p{name} = ...` and numbers via `\n{name} = ...` that you can refer to from inside the `let` operation (here a `node`). If you have a point like `\p0`, then you can refer to its components as `\x0` and `\y0`.

For `\p2`, I used another feature of the `calc` library, a so-called "partway modifier." `(\p0)!.5!(\p1)` means the point halfway between `\p0` and `\p1`. The [pgf manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) has all the details of both of these.

Note that you should [probably](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles) be using `\tikzset` rather than `\tikzstyle`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with a `fit` node. In this case node contents has to be added as a centered `label` (as it's explained in section 57: Fitting library)

Sometimes we forget that the `fit` list of a fitting node is used just to fix its size, but it's position is not restricted to be around fitted nodes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3.5em, minimum width=4.5em]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [block,align=center](a) {A};
\node [block,align=center,right=1cm of a](b) {B};
\node [block, fit= (a) (b), inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth, below right=1cm and 0 of a.south west, label=center:C](c) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]